# Install different version of same application in osx

Tags: macos, ubuntu, installation, parallels

This is very similar to [this unresolved question](https://superuser.com/questions/411048/install-two-different-versions-of-same-application-on-osx), but I would very much like to install two versions of the same application in OSX. How can you do this and what is the best way to do it?

Specifically, I currently have [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/) 5 installed on my laptop virtualizing, among other things, [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) 10.04. I tried to install Ubuntu 12.04 this morning and there was a problem installing it in the old version of Parallels. As a work around, I was wondering if I can install Parallels 8 (alongside my existing version of Parallels) in which I can virtualize Ubuntu 12.04. Any suggestions here?

**Update:** I suppose I could use another virtual machine (e.g. VMWare) to host my second version of Ubuntu. I prefer the Parallels framework as a colleague of mine has been extremely dissatisfied with his VMWare experiment. I further suppose that I could risk updating Parallels but I am (unnecessarily?) concerned that the upgrade might affect my virtual machines.

Comment: Is VMWare not an option if you don't need to run programs at the same time?

Comment: Does Parallels have an installer, or is it a simple drag&drop into your Applications folder?

Comment: @Darth It has an installer since it creates virtual network interfaces et cetera

Comment: How does having an installer affect things? Is that what makes it problematic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the absence of a better solution, I ended up upgrading my Parallels. I suppose this was [the obvious solution to begin with](https://twitter.com/adamrpah/status/246609402524737537); I was just averse to trying such a thing in the middle of a rather large project. Thanks everyone for your comments and feedback.